# Important or interesting mathematical objects that are fixed points

Tags: big-list, fixed-points

I've observed that many interesting or important objects that arise in mathematics later turn out to be **fixed points** for some function (possibly in a way that is not obvious from their original definition). What are some examples of this phenomenon?

Here are a few I could think of off the top of my head:

- The **[golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)** $\varphi \approx 1.618033...$ is a fixed
  point for the function $x \mapsto 1/(x-1)$, the other fixed point
  being $-1/\varphi$.
- The [**Thue-Morse sequence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is obtained by starting with $0$,
  and at each stage appending the Boolean complement of what you
  currently have (so $0$, $01$, $0110$, $01101001$, ...). This turns
  out to be a fixed point of the function $\{ 0,1 \}^\mathbb{N} \to \{
     0,1 \}^\mathbb{N}$ which replaces each $0$ with $01$ and each $1$
  with $10$.
- An **initial algebra** for an endofunctor $F\colon \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ turns out to be a fixed point of $F$ ([Lambek's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor#LambeksTheorem)).

Since everything is a fixed point for the identity function, maybe we'll restrict to objects which turn out to be the unique fixed point of something, or at least one of a small number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this counts, but one proof of the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) shows that the unique solution to the ODE

$$y'=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0$$

can be thought of as the unique fixed point of the function operator $L$ defined by

$$L(\phi(x))=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\phi(t))\text{ }dt$$

As shown in the Wikipedia article, if $f$ satisfies the assumptions of the theorem, the fixed point will exist as a consequence of the Banach fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The multiples of the exponential function $\exp\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ (that is, the functions of the form $x\mapsto\lambda e^x$) are the fixed points of $D\colon C^\infty(\Bbb R)\longrightarrow C^\infty(\Bbb R)$, with $D(f)=f'$.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number) is a fixed point of the cosine function. It is in fact the only real fixed point (other fixed points are complex numbers).